# Combining 2 or more datasets onto the same Line Chart SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: charts, sql-server-2008-r2, dataset

I am fairly knew to SQL Report Builder and I currently have four different DataSets that are displaying data on 4 line charts. I want to be able to combine these all into 1 chart with 4 different lines.

Here is my example query for one of my data sets.

```
SELECT 
    QA_Automation_Datalogs_1.Log_Time,
    QA_Automation_Datalogs_1.Y_Bed_Position, 
FROM 
    QA_Automation_Datalogs_1 
WHERE 
    QA_Automation_Datalogs_1.Location = @Plant AND 
    QA_Automation_Datalogs_1.Log_Time >= @start_date AND 
    QA_Automation_Datalogs_1.Log_Time  < @stop_date AND
    QA_Automation_Datalogs_1.Bed_Number = 1
ORDER BY 
    QA_Automation_Datalogs_1.Log_Time
```

For the different data sets I am changing the WHERE Bed_Number to 1,2,3, and 4. 
I then am graphing the bed position as a function of time. I have tried using both Lookup functions and JOIN/UNION functions but they have not been working( could be due to some syntax errors). I also am not able to change how the data is arranged in the server.

Sorry I forgot to mention that after I get the data I create a calculated field "Position" and set it equal to "Y_Bed_Position". I then am graphing the Sum(Fields!Position.Value). If I obtain all the data at once like I believe you have shown me, I am not sure how to Sum() each individual bed together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be missing something, but as I understand your question I think this should get the data you seek.

```
SELECT
     QA_Automation_Datalogs_1.Log_Time,
     QA_Automation_Datalogs_1.Bed_Number,
     QA_Automation_Datalogs_1.Y_Bed_Position, 
FROM 
    QA_Automation_Datalogs_1 
WHERE 
    QA_Automation_Datalogs_1.Location = @Plant AND 
    QA_Automation_Datalogs_1.Log_Time >= @start_date AND 
    QA_Automation_Datalogs_1.Log_Time  < @stop_date AND
    QA_Automation_Datalogs_1.Bed_Number in (1, 2, 3, 4)
ORDER BY 
    QA_Automation_Datalogs_1.Log_Time,
    QA_Automation_Datalogs_1.Bed_Number
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that after I get the data I create a calculated field "Position" and set it equal to "Y_Bed_Position". I then am graphing the Sum(Fields!Position.Value). If I obtain all the data at once like I believe you have shown me, I am not sure how to Sum() each individual bed together.

Comment: I think we are going to need some sample data along with the results you are getting and what you hope to get. That will help us help you.

Comment: I figured it out your correction did work but I had to additionally go to series properties for the chart and choose my category as log time. Thanks!